# Trying to select a random word from a website Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am making a 'Hangman' game and would like to have python select a random word from a website. But it keeps printing as `b'word'`  and would like to know how to fix this so that it is just word.

My code:

```
import random
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain') as response:
   html = response.read()

word_list = html.split()
word_chocie = random.choice(word_list)
word = word_chocie.strip("b")
print(word)
```

I keep getting this error and not sure how to fix it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/hangman.py", line 23, in <module>
    word = word_chocie.strip("b")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Have you tried something? where's the struggle? what's not working? If you tried, please share what you got; If not - StackOverflow is not a place to ask someone to write code for you.

Comment: Have changed now. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: It looks better now. You need to wait that people with enough reputation will review your edit in order to re-open the question for accepting answers.

Comment: Instead of `html = response.read()`, do `html = response.read().decode('utf-8')`. You do not need to remove `'b'`, it is not actually part of the string. See here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples

Comment: I can't post an answer because this is closed, but this is ripe for a Reversal badge :)

Comment: Just came back to see if the question was opened for answering, you've got an answer :)

Comment: @C.Sa you got it working?

Comment: @arieljannai Yes thank you that helped so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct version of you code - the problem was that you were having a `bytes` object instead of the `str` you probably expected.
I added a `.decode('utf-8')` to the content read from the website, and now the html is an `str` object.
You recieved the error because you were working on a `bytes` object (the `word_chocie`), as `str`.

Note that the `b` prefix you had in `word_chocie` (`b'hello'`) is python's mark that this object is of type `bytes`.

```
import random
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain') as response:
    html = response.read().decode('utf-8')

word_list = html.split()
word_chocie = random.choice(word_list)
print(word_chocie)
```

Comment: @C.Sa Great. Since the answer worked you, you should **`accept`** the answer by clicking the checkmark (`V`). It marks the question as answered and having a satisfying answer.